# How to fade out and stop an AudioPlayer in AudioKit 5 versus just stopping it

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit, akaudioplayer

In Audiokit 4, AKAudioPlayer had

```
fadeInTime
fadeOutTime
```

Which let me stop and start everything more smoothly.

while AudioPlayer in AudioKit 5 does not.

How do I get the same behaviour in the current version of the library?

Is it a question of ramping the volume to zero and then stopping it in the completion handler? I just worry I am doing extra work here, if I am missing the fading powers that exist.

Comment: [fadeOutTime](https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKAudioPlayer.html#/c:@M@AudioKit@objc(cs)AKAudioPlayer(py)fadeOutTime) is still there, so this is potentially a bug

Comment: i tried both fadeoutTime and fadeOutTime and it would not compile

Comment: They are still in the library, so it may be worthwhile flagging this directly with AudioKit https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues